# Rename a table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, syntax-error, table-rename

Renaming a table is not working in MySQL

```
RENAME TABLE group TO member;
```

The error message is

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
        to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group 
        RENAME TO member' at line 1
```

The query is working fine on other tables for me, but not with this particular table `group`.

Comment: [here's the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rename-table.html)

Comment: Both sqls are the same. Try this **rename table 'group' to member**

Comment: This illustrates nicely how pointless it is to use all-caps for keywords.

Comment: No, it does not. All-caps keywords improve readability and are expected standard style.

Answer (score 577):

`group` is a keyword (part of [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)) in MySQL, you need to surround it with backticks(`) to let MySQL know that you want it interpreted as a table name:

```
RENAME TABLE `group` TO `member`;
```

**added**(see comments)- Those are not single quotes.

Comment: And yes you need the back tick `  and not the single quote '  I did the single quote from habit, and got the error, but maybe this will save someone else 10 seconds

Comment: Some keywords, such as NAME are still available without back ticks. I think this availability it is a bad practice, which should be removed one day from MySQL

Comment: Or don't use keywords for tables or columns.

Comment: DO NOT USE KEYWORDS FOR TABLES OR COLUMNS.

Answer (score 154):

Please try

```
RENAME TABLE  `oldTableName` TO  `newTableName`
```

Comment: See [the answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12650388/3397217) for why you should consider using the backticks. @coder

Answer (score 44):

The MySQL syntax for [`RENAME TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/rename-table.html) statement is the following:

```sql
RENAME TABLE <old_table_name> TO <new_table_name>
```

In your query, you've used `group` which is one of the *keywords* in MySQL. Try to avoid MySQL *keywords* for names while creating tables, field names and so on.

Answer (score 28):

```
ALTER TABLE old_table_name RENAME new_table_name;
```

or

```
RENAME TABLE old_table_name TO new_table_name;
```

Answer (score 23):

Table name change

```
RENAME TABLE old_table_name TO new_table_name;
```

Answer (score 20):

**Rename a table in MySQL :**

```
ALTER TABLE current_name RENAME new_name;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer. Just show code is not a good practice.

Answer (score 14):

group - is a reserved word in MySQL, that's why you see such error.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
        to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group 
        RENAME TO member' at line 1
```

You need to wrap table name into **backticks**:

```
RENAME TABLE `group` TO `member`;
```

Answer (score 13):

```
ALTER TABLE `group` RENAME `member`
```

group is keyword so you must have to enclose into `group`

Answer (score 12):

For `Mysql 5.6.18` use the following command

`` ALTER TABLE `old_table` RENAME TO  `new_table` ``

Also if there is an error saying ".... near RENAME TO ..." try removing the tick `` ` ``

Answer (score 9):

```
RENAME TABLE tb1 TO tb2;
```

tb1 - current table name.
tb2 - the name you want your table to be called.

Answer (score 9):

According to [mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rename-table.html): "to rename `TEMPORARY` tables, `RENAME TABLE` does not work. Use `ALTER TABLE` instead."

So this is the most portable method:

```
ALTER TABLE `old_name` RENAME `new_name`;
```

Answer (score 6):

Try any of these

```
RENAME TABLE `group` TO `member`;
```

**or**

```
ALTER TABLE `group` RENAME `member`;
```

Answer (score 5):

> Rename table 
> Syntax
> The syntax to rename a table in MySQL is:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
RENAME TO new_table_name;
```

> Example 
> Let's look at an example that shows how to rename a table in MySQL using the ALTER TABLE statement. 
>  or example:

```
ALTER TABLE contacts
RENAME TO people;
```

Answer (score 2):

Running The **Alter** Command

1.Click the **SQL** tab at the top.

2.In the text box enter the following command: `ALTER TABLE exampletable RENAME TO new_table_name;`

3.Click the go button.

source : https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/help/2158

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
RENAME TABLE `group` TO `member`;
```

Use back tick (`) instead of single quote (').

Answer (score -1):

Without giving the database name the table is can't be renamed in my case, I followed the below command to rename the table.

```
RENAME TABLE current_db.tbl_name TO current_db.tbl_name;
```

Answer (score -6):

Right Click on View > New Query

And Type:
EXEC sp_rename 'Table', 'NewName'

Then Click on Run button at the top left corner of the page.

Comment: MySQL not Transact SQL