# RENAME TABLE / ALTER TABLE not working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to rename a table in a Mysql db, from PHP, but this code doesn't work:

```
$sql = "RENAME TABLE dbname.table TO dbname.tabletmp;"; 
$conn->query($sql);
```

I've tried to use also `ALTER TABLE` or the `''` for the table names, but nothing. Any ideas?

It seems that in PHP `ALTER TABLE` isn't a command :/

Comment: Are you getting some exception or error message?
Rename table syntax looks fine. Alter table cannot be used for renaming table.

Comment: you get any error messages?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37786534/5513005) may help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename a table in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650370/rename-a-table-in-mysql)

Comment: First `use DATABASE_NAME` and then `RENAME TABLE tb1 TO tb2;`

Comment: No, i haven't any exception or error message. The page stops loading when arrives at that line of code...

Comment: @MilanChheda now the page load properly, but the query doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that in PHP ALTER TABLE isn't a command :/

PHP doesn't care about SQL. Not even `$conn->query()` cares about it. You pass it a string and it passes it further to the server.

Make sure the user you use to connect has the necessary privileges to rename a table. The [documentation of `RENAME TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rename-table.html) says:

> When you execute `RENAME TABLE`, you cannot have any locked tables or active transactions. You must also have the `ALTER` and `DROP` privileges on the original table, and the `CREATE` and `INSERT` privileges on the new table.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$sql = "RENAME TABLE `" . $oldname . "` TO `" . $newname . "`" ;
$conn->query($sql);
```