# org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement with oracle

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, exception

I am got this exception when I run my MVC project with Hibernate inserting the view data into a database. How do I solve this exception and how to insert the data into an Oracle database?

> GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement this the exception

## exception

```
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.84
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Dec 7 2023 19:27:40 UTC
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version number: 9.0.84.0
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 11
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Users\P.PRASANNA\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.7.v20230425-1502\jre
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           17.0.7+7
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Eclipse Adoptium
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\P.PRASANNA\eclipse-workspace\servlet Programs\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\P.PRASANNA\eclipse-workspace\servlet Programs\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\P.PRASANNA\eclipse-workspace\servlet Programs\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Users\P.PRASANNA\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.7.v20230425-1502\jre\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Users/P.PRASANNA/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.7.v20230425-1502/jre/bin/server;C:/Users/P.PRASANNA/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.7.v20230425-1502/jre/bin;C:\Users\P.PRASANNA\Downloads\WINDOWS.X64_193000_db_home\bin;C:\Users\P.PRASANNA\AppData\Local\Temp\Temp7_WINDOWS.X64_193000_db_home.zip\bin;C:\Users\P.PRASANNA\AppData\Local\Temp\Temp3_WINDOWS.X64_193000_db_home.zip\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\P.PRASANNA\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\P.PRASANNA\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\P.PRASANNA\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.16.1\bin;;C:\Users\P.PRASANNA\OneDrive\Desktop;;.]
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:41 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-2525"]
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Server initialization in [596] milliseconds
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.84]
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:43 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:43 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-2525"]
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in [2329] milliseconds
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'spring'
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:44 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: Initializing Servlet 'spring'
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:46 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.3.Final}
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:46 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:46 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:46 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:46 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
Hibernate: create table User (id number(10,0) not null, userEmail varchar2(255 char), userName varchar2(255 char), userPassword varchar2(255 char), primary key (id))
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:49 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:524)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:470)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:493)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:710)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:616)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:600)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1444)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:591)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1063)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:747)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:670)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:92Hibernate: create sequence hibernate_sequence start with 1 increment by 1
8)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1794)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00903: invalid table name

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:509)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:461)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1104)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:553)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:269)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:655)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:229)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:41)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:928)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1205)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1823)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1778)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:303)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: Error : 903, Position : 13, Sql = create table User (id number(10,0) not null, userEmail varchar2(255 char), userName varchar2(255 char), userPassword varchar2(255 char), primary key (id)), OriginalSql = create table User (id number(10,0) not null, userEmail varchar2(255 char), userName varchar2(255 char), userPassword varchar2(255 char), primary key (id)), Error Msg = ORA-00903: invalid table name

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:513)
    ... 88 more

Dec 22, 2023 2:24:52 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: Completed initialization in 7166 ms
Dec 22, 2023 2:24:52 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping for GET /SpringMVCProject/
User [userName=rr, userEmail=, userPassword=eee]
User [userName=pprasannakumar264@gmail.com, userEmail=pprasannakumar264@gmail.com, userPassword=eee]
Dec 22, 2023 2:50:16 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping for GET /SpringMVCProject/
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename a table in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650370/rename-a-table-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the table name from "User" to something else like "AppUsers" or something. Word User is reserved by Oracle.
See the full list of reserved names here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a42525/apb.htm

Comment: ok it work data stroed in appuser table thank you for your responce